# Custom view widget

Tags: android, view, widget

I was browsing internet for tutorial on custom view widget creatin, but they all were creating views of regular form, like rectangle, circle. But I need a widget that looks something like this: [image]

Can you help me with brief overlook on how I create it? All that matters is outline form. I need it to be animated - I can extend it and shrink.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shape drawables mentioned here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for making your own custom view by drawing the layouts on the canvas and providing it with the necessary functionalities you should look into this

[Custom views](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)